# Is there a way to remove autotruncation from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am attempting to create a multi index dataframe which contains every possible index even ones where it does not currently contain values. I wish to set these non-existent values to 0. To achieve this, I used the following:

```
index_levels = ['Channel', 'Duration', 'Designation', 'Manufacturing Class']

grouped_df = df.groupby(by = index_levels)[['Total Purchases', 'Sales', 'Cost']].agg('sum')

grouped_df = grouped_df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(grouped_df.index.levels), fill_value = 0)
```

The expected result:

```
 ___________________________________________________________________________________________ 
|Chan. | Duration   | Designation|    Manufact. |Total Purchases|  Sales      |   Cost      |
|______|____________|____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      | Month      | Special    |    Brand     |     0         |    0.00     |   0.00      |
|      |            |            |______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      |            |            |    Generic   |     0         |    0.00     |   0.00      |
|Retail|            |____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      |            |Not Special |    Brand     |     756       | 15654.07    |   9498.23   |
|      |            |            |______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      |            |            |    Generic   |     7896      |  98745.23   |    78953.56 |
|      |____________|____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      | Season     | Special    |    Brand     |     0         |  0.00       |    0.00     |
|      |            |            |______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      |            |            |    Generic   |     0         |  0.00       |    0.00     |
|      |            |____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      |            |Not Special |    Brand     |     0         |  0.00       |    0.00     |
|      |            |            |______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      |            |            |    Generic   |     0         |  0.00       |    0.00     |
|______|____________|____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
```

This result is produced when at least one of the index levels contains a value. However, if the index level does not contain any value, then the following result is produced below.

```
___________________________________________________________________________________________ 
|Chan. | Duration   | Designation|    Manufact. |Total Purchases|  Sales      |   Cost      |
|______|____________|____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      | Month      | Not Special|    Brand     |     756       |  15654.07   |   9498.23   |
|      |            |            |______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      |            |            |    Generic   |    7896       | 98745.23    |   78953.56  |
|Retail|____________|____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      | Season     |Not Special |    Brand     |       0       |    0.00     |     0.00    |
|      |            |            |______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
|      |            |            |    Generic   |       0       |    0.00     |     0.00    |
|______|____________|____________|______________|_______________|_____________|_____________|
```

For some reason, the values continue to be autotruncated. How can I fix indices so that the desired result is always produced and I can always reliably use these indices for calculations, even when said indices have no values in them?

Comment: I can't reproduce this (pandas 1.3.2). Could you edit your question with a runnable example?

Comment: I have edited the example to make it reproducible. I believe now you will be able to verify my example @PeterLeimbigler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is construct the desired fixed index beforehand. For instance, based on a dictionary where the keys are the columns labels used as group index, and the values are all the possible outcomes.

```
index_levels = {
    'Channel': ['Retails'], 
    'Duration': ['Month', 'Season'], 
    'Designation': ['Special', 'Not Special'], 
    'Manufacturing Class': ['Brand', 'Generic']
}

fixed_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(index_levels.values(), names=index_levels.keys())
```

Then you can do

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(by=index_levels.keys())[['Total Purchases', 'Sales', 'Cost']].agg('sum')

grouped_df = grouped_df.reindex(fixed_index, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: My index levels are based upon the columns of another dataframe. Channel, Duration, Designation, and Manufacturing Class are all columns. Is there a way to set the index levels based upon these columns and then use them inside of the fixed_index instead?

Comment: I'm not following. What do you mean by "set the index levels based upon these columns and then use them inside of the fixed_index instead"?

Comment: Apologies, these columns come from an already existing dataframe which contains a single index. I am attempting to create a multiindex dataframe from the four columns: Channel, Duration, Designation, and manufacturing class. I don't know if I can create index levels using these columns, or if I have to create these index levels using what you've provided here. For example, can I just take index levels and create a code like: `index_levels = { df['Channel'], df['Duration'], df['Designation'], df['Manufacturing Class']}`. Is this possible, or am I better off using your method?

Comment: Thanks, much clearer! Yes, you can, I will update my answer with a better solution.

Comment: @QuestionAskerandAnswerer does the new solution work for you?

Comment: I am attempting to implement it now. Give me some time. I do believe it will work however.

Comment: I just simplified it. There was no need to `index_levels_values`to be a dictionary.

Comment: I don't know if this list format will work, but I will attempt it. I will inform you under this same reply whether or not it works in 20 minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution has not worked. I will double check my work and see if there is something wrong on my end.

Comment: I just realized that what I was saying about your code attempt  is wrong. Apologies... I was misinterpreting it, it should work indeed. The only explanation for not working in the second example is that the 'Designation' column of `df` doesn't contain any 'Special' value, or if it does, it's paired with at least one missing value in the other index columns . In that case, my new solution won't work either.  Is that what you were trying to say in the post description?

Comment: Yes, there isn't any values and I just want to replace the none values with 0. Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree attempting this solution?

Comment: If the column doesn't contain that value from the beginning, `pandas` can't know that it should be included in the corresponding index level . Each index column must have at least one sample of the level values. The only way to include inexistent values is to manually create the desired index beforehand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238475/discussion-between-question-asker-and-answerer-and-harryplotter).

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. I will remove the second solution since it doesn't work.